# How can Java JMF control my Mac camera?

Tags: java, jmf

I try to use JMF to capture image using my Mac's camera. But the result of following code shows I have no available device.

```
Vector v = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);
System.out.println("size = " + v.size());
```

Is it the case that Mac does not allow JMF to control its camera?
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIR JMF could only handle camera resolutions up to 640 x 480 px.  As such, I would not be surprised if it does not detect/support modern cameras, which went past that resolution a long time ago.

The solution might be to *not* use an API that was abandoned by Sun over a decade ago.  It was a great API in its time, but times change, and it ..didn't.

- [Java-FX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html)?  I added a ? to that since I have not used it, and am not sure if the [`Media`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html) source of the [`MediaPlayer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) can be a video camera.
- [VLCJ](https://code.google.com/p/vlcj/). Is a more general purpose media handling API, though again I've never used it personally.

Comment: But actually, JMF can detect my Mac's camera on Windows Platform of my mac. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Do you know any java media library to capture live video stream so that i can broadcast it to other clients?

Comment: *"But actually, JMF can detect my Mac's camera on Windows Platform of my mac."*  What the huh?  What is 'Windows Platform'?  What resolution is it picking it up at?  *"capture live video stream so that i can broadcast it to other clients"*  I *think* VLCJ can do that.

Comment: I install Windows on my Mac using bootcamp. JMF can detect iSight on windows~